# concatenate large (>100MB) multiple (say 10) csv files using python

Tags: python, csv, concatenation, large-files

I have 12 large csv files with same structure.
I would like to combine all the csv files into single csv file.
Don't repeat the headers.
Now I am using `shutil` as follows.

```py
import shutil
import time
csv_files = ['file1.csv', 'file2.csv', 'file3.csv', 'file4.csv', 'file5.csv', 'file6.csv']

target_file_name = 'target.csv';
start_time = time.time()
shutil.copy(csv_files[0], target_file_name)
with open(target_file_name, 'a') as out_file:
    for source_file in csv_files[1:]:
        with open(source_file, 'r') as in_file:
            in_file.readline()
            shutil.copyfileobj(in_file, out_file)
            in_file.close()
    out_file.close()
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

### Edit

When I tried `time cat file[1-4].csv > BigBoy` command in the terminal I got the following output.
`0.08s user 4.57s system 60% cpu 7.644 total`.
That is cat command took about 4.5 seconds, but Python program took 17.46 seconds. I used 4 csv files, each having 116MB size.

I would like to know, if any other methods are there in Python, to handle these scenario more efficiently.
You could download large csv files from [here](https://www.stats.govt.nz/large-datasets/csv-files-for-download/).

Comment: Yes, efficiently. I edited my post. Thanks

Comment: I tried the code snippet with 4 csv files of size 116MB. It took 17.46 seconds. I would like to know if any other library/methods are there which handles file operations more efficiently.

Comment: Try the shell to see how fast your disks are `time cat file[1-4].csv > BigBoy`

Comment: about 4.5 seconds `0.08s user 4.57s system 60% cpu 7.644 total`

Comment: Ok, that comparison now makes sense. Thanks for providing the information. Comments may be deleted. If you [edit] those two numbers into the questions, we have documented the room for improvement

Comment: I won't post it as an answer because you asked for a Python solution, but it seems the fastest way to get the job done is to start a subprocess and run the following in order not to repeat the headers `awk '(FNR>1)||(NR==1)' file1.csv file2.csv file3.csv...`

Answer (score 2):

Better use csvstack from csvkit for this. There is also a lot of other stuff to work with csv files from console.

```sh
csvstack file1.csv file2.csv ...
```